# How to add card in React Native (Best approach with minimum size)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning react native. When i searched for Card in React native, i got confused as there are many card libraries.

Just one question, what you guys prefer. when you need `CardView` in React native with minimum size and best controls.

https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/card.html

https://github.com/dale-french/react-native-cards

https://github.com/jacklam718/react-native-card-view

https://github.com/talut/react-native-simple-card-view

Comment: Create a card component yourself, personally I would not use a third party library for such an easy component.

Comment: I am new to react native, can you show your example props for making card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you to create your own or you can use native-base's card components...
nativa-base link is http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#card-image-headref

Comment: So if some one want to add card, then he will need to add whole native base library in his project. Does not sound good.

Comment: Can you show me your custom CarView component. If you have one?